# Force one window when opening multiple files

Tags: buffers, window, window-splitting

Any time I open multiple files I'd like emacs to only show me one buffer. I do not want any split windows. This would save me a keystroke every time.

I learned I could do away with the buffer list from this [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36364/how-to-open-multiple-files-without-automatically-activating-the-buffer-list-sp) with `(setq-default inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)`. But, now another buffer just replaces what would have been the buffer list. Any way to force only one window when opening multiple files?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you open files with `emacs file1 file2` and want to avoid the windows splitting by default at startup? IMO, it's better to open Emacs then `find-file` as you don't have any startup latency.

Comment: That would be a workaround, yes, but I have bash functions that open up workflows and projects, for which it would be tedious to `C-x C-e` every file. Latency has never been a noticeable issue.

Comment: Do you want something like this perhaps: `emacs  --eval '(find-file-noselect "a")' --eval '(find-file-noselect "b")' c` ? This opens `a` and `b` but does not select them and then opens `c`.

Comment: That would do the job, yes, but I was hoping for a solution that allowed me to set the behavior in my `init` so that I can continue to open files normally, now with the desired behavior. It's not that important to me to choose which file gets the single window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your last comment, but try the following in your init file:

```el
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(setq command-line-functions (list #'handle-files))

(defun handle-files ()
  (let* ((files (cons argi command-line-args-left))
         (lastfile (car (last files)))
         (files (butlast files)))
    (while files
      (find-file-noselect (car files))
      (setq files (cdr files)))
    (if lastfile
      (find-file lastfile))
    (setq command-line-args-left nil)
    t))
```

The assumption is that all the options are already processed and you just have a list of files at the end of your command line. Each function in the list `command-line-functions` is called with no args (do `C-h i g (elisp)command-line-arguments` to read the relevant section of the Elisp manual in emacs or see the online [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html#Command_002dLine-Arguments) for details). There is only one function in this case and it consumes all of the left-over arguments: it does a `find-file-noselect` on all of them except the last one, on which it does a `find-file`.

Doing `emacs -Q -l /path/to/init/file.el a b c d` does what you want (I think).

EDIT: per the OP's comment, I fixed up the code so that it works with 0, 1 and 2 file arguments. By induction, it has to work for any number of arguments :-)

Comment: Thank you for putting this together. It does do the desired behavior, but what I meant in the last comment is I'd like to put a function or setting in my `init` and then open files as normal with `emacs a b c d`. Would it be simpler to add some sort of hook that executes `delete-other-windows` after opening files from the command line as described?

Comment: That's exactly what this is supposed to do: did you try putting it into your init file and then starting emacs?

Comment: It does, but I now have to issue it with the `-Q -l` options. I think adding a hook to `delete-other-windows` would be the cleanest solution. I'm not sure what to hook on though? If you come up with an answer like that I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: No, just put the code in your init file as is and then restart normally: no `-Q -l` needed. It should just work.

Comment: That's odd, maybe I was doing something wrong. Still, don't you think a hook would be much cleaner?

Comment: This is pretty low-level stuff. I could not find a hook that would operate at that level.

Comment: Went to mark as solved, but ran into an issue when using it for a single file `emacs .emacs`. `find-file-noselect: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Fixed (I hope). Let me know one way or the other.

Comment: Yup, the fix works!

Comment: I've since asked [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/70463/28734) which led to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36369/28734) (see the update). I no longer have regular emacs to try, but you think `(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'delete-other-windows)` would work? This is along the lines of what I was suggesting when I mentioned finding a hook.