# Force one window when opening multiple files spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, buffers

Looking for the spacemacs answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61523/28734).

How do I have spacemacs open as if I had issued `SPC w m` (`spacemacs/toggle-maximize-buffer`)?

I thought it might be `dotspacemacs-maximized-at-startup`, but this affects the frame.

Comment: Have you tried adding `spacemacs/toggle-maximize-buffer` to `window-setup-hook`? Similar to what is shown in the update here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36369/36872 where `(add-hook 'window-setup-hook #'delete-other-windows)` was used instead.

Comment: Incredible! That worked: `(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-maximize-buffer)`. I don't think the `#` is needed though. Please add this as an answer!

Comment: @young_souvlaki The `#` is indeed not strictly necessary, but you'll often see it recommended as good style, since it distinguishes general symbols from function symbols for the benefit of the (human) reader, as well as the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add `spacemacs/toggle-maximize-buffer` to `window-setup-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook #'spacemacs/toggle-maximize-buffer)
```

Add this to the `dotspacemacs/user-init` function of your `.spacemacs` file.

Similar to what is shown in the update [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36369/36872), where `(add-hook 'window-setup-hook #'delete-other-windows)` was used instead.